# Mains Voltage Distortion Question

Tags: mains, distortion

[image]

I am studying the effect of a diode rectifier on the mains. When I started to increase the inductance, the current had less distortion but the input voltage became more distorted. When I looked at the FFT analysis it had allot of 3rd order harmonic content. So is my understanding correct in saying that by designing a 3rd order filter by placing a capacitor in parallel with the inductor on the input, then it can reduce the distortion of the voltage at the input ?

Comment: I think there is a GND connection missing in your schematic.

Comment: The ground is on the neutral of the supply

Comment: The diagram does not show that you are measuring distortion on the mains. The oscilloscopes are between the series input inductance and the rectifier.

Comment: Thats because mains usually have inductances present

Comment: The inductor on the input can be either a simulation of the source inductance or harmonic mitigation for the rectifier it can not be both.